# Choice of antenna connector type for handheld radio transceiver

Tags: connector, mobile, sub-ghz

I am wondering about "the best" antenna connector type for a handheld radio transceiver, sub-GHz, 10 W, two independent RF chains (thus, the handheld has 2 antenna connectors), and I've considered:

- BNC
- Type N
- SMA
- MCX
- MMCX
- SSMCX
- FAKRA

I've researched some technical parameters (eg all of them cover sub-GHz and have lifetime matings 500-1000 max.) as well as part availability, and I would currently lean to SSMCX, e.g. Molex 73415-4670.

However, I am actually a software guy, not that deep into RF, and SSMCX seems exotic, when half the world is using Type N or SMA? But Type N is huuuge, and SMA isn't quick plug but threaded. What should I choose? What are commonly used types in professional handheld RF transceivers?

Thanks for any hints, tips or opinions!

Comment: Threaded connectors give better performance, in general. There's a quick-mate version of SMA called QMA, but it's a little exotic too. I like MCX, but I don't do anything beyond a few dozen MHz, so I'm unsure if it has problems beyond there.

Comment: Thanks for your comment and hints! I wasn't aware of QMA at all;) Had a look, specifically distributor part availability .. it does seem a bit exotic. Wikipedia says it "was designed as a quick plug SMA and Type N successor" .. but it doesn't quite seem to have replaced those. FWIW, without special considerations, I'd choose Type N, also because of "no performance worries definitely", but: I want something smaller, quick plug, for handheld. Mmmh. I only need 80m-10m and 70cm - and probably 2m and 30cm. Maybe TV white spectrum. But definitely all sub-GHz and low power ..

Comment: I'm not used to using wavelength measurements, what do those correspond to in terms of frequency?

Comment: Also, it would be useful to know: is this for an external connector that will be responsible for mechanically holding the antenna as well, or is it for an internal connector with the antenna mechanically attached by some other means?

Comment: I terms of frequency: 80m ~ 4 MHz, 10m ~ 30 MHz, 70 cm ~ 450 MHz, 30cm ~ 850 MHz. Those antenna connectors are not for holding the antennas (any stub or such), but really for attaching antennas via 50 Ohm coax cables, e.g. RF1 for an inverted dipole on 40m, and RF2 for a quarter wave vertical on 70cm or similar, or RF1 and RF2 both inverted and crossed dipoles on 40/80m or ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe BNC.

Not any of the other ones:

- Type N - Vintage, large, not that great performance
- SMA - Microwave connectors usually for interior use, may not withstand the rigors of a handheld.
- MCX, MMCX, SSMCX - Microwave connectors most suitable for interior use, not ideal for exterior use in a handheld radio (too delicate).
- FAKRA - only usable for interior connectors in vehicles

TNC is commonly used in transceivers: high-power, rugged, threaded, very common. That's what I would recommend.

Check what's available in off-the-shelf antennas for your frequency,  pick one that works for you, and then use its connector.

You may want to check this [complete list](https://connectorbook.com/identification.html?m=NN&n=std_exterior_rf_conn) of industry-standard exterior coax connector. (My site.)

Comment: Interesting! Thanks a lot for you comments and some perspective! I need to look at TNC more closely (even though I don't need >10W power). BNC is sadly also large, I've looked at the Amphenol 31-5640-1010 - which is PCB through hole with almost 16mm height. There doesn't seem any SMT. The SSMCX is 2.3mm and SMT. I am really wondering: what type of connector do professional _handheld_ transceivers (or receivers only for that matter) use? Are such devices really still "brick like" .. e.g. 3cm thick or what?

Comment: The SSMCX is really for interior use (as I said). It has no latching: the antenna would just fall off. If you need small, then SMA is the best choice, even though it's more delicate than a TNC.

Comment: "some perspective". I just finished a book on connectors, for which I had to do a lot of research, including on coax connectors.

Comment: Apologies for not fully recognizing you as pretty much "expert" on connectors! I just saw your book "The Electronic Connector Book" on you SO profile;) I will have a deep look into TNC, as that is what you seem to recommend. Also, rgd SSMCX: alright, I got it. Maybe the wrong choice. A handheld doesn't need to be as rugged as a cell tower outdoor box .. no IP67 or shenanigans ... but still, it needs to be more robust than a sat modem that lives under the shelf. Still want to wait for possible more comments/answers though ..

Comment: "A handheld doesn't need to be as rugged as a cell tower outdoor box .. no IP67 or shenanigans ... but still, it needs to be more robust than a sat modem that lives under the shelf. " You got it!

Comment: One more question rgd TNC in particular if I may. I've looked at Amphenol TNC products, for PCB mount right angle: there seems to be 3 variants. All of them have the threading at the end to screw the connecting terminal (obviously), but one has threading throughout to screw the jack into the enclosure, one has the threading interrupted (not sure .. is that called "bulkhead"?), and one has no threading at all, so all mechanical forces need to be consumed by the PCB, and a forth one has IP67 sealing in addition. Do I need to remove all forces from PCB, do I need/want bulkhead?

Comment: Can't help, but need to remark;) all of them are crazy expensive, plus bulky: the device would be at least 20mm, only because of the connectors. Well, maybe one price has to be paid.

Comment: In that case, I won't spend time answering your additional question in any detail. Let me just say that the different models are secured to the panel in different ways, on not at all.

Comment: Interesting reaction - I have no clue what I might have said to upset you, but that wasn't my intention. But anyways, thanks a lot for your help so far, and have a nice day!

Comment: Oh my gosh! No, I am not upset at all! I was about to spend 15 minutes making drawings for you. When you said "TNC is too expensive"  I figured you're going for some other connector, so no sense telling you about TNC mounting. I am so sorry that I gave you the the wrong impression. I _DO_ want to help you if I can!

Comment: If money is an issue, did you consider permanent antennas?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/149134/discussion-between-oberstet-and-davide-andrea).

Comment: Alright, I had a look into TNC, and I am quite convinced your strong hint is pretty good;) I will somehow work/design around TNC dimensions and prices I guess. also accepted your answer. fwiw, two details that might be of interest for other looking here, one device that is certainly for robust outdoor use is the L3Harris Falcon IV AN/PRC-171, which uses TNC. In the HAM world specifically, TNC seems also to be used even though plain BNC might be seen more often. Dunno. Anyways, thanks again for the hint!